# Mapbox Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, leaflet, mapbox

I managed to get Leaflet working with Angular 2 and Webpack by following this project.

[angular 2 leaflet starter](https://github.com/haoliangyu/angular2-leaflet-starter)

I can see the typings configured in "browser.d.ts":

```
/// <reference path="browser\ambient\leaflet\leaflet.d.ts" />
```

webpack.config.js defines an entry point:

```
...
entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'libs': './src/libs.ts',
    'main': './src/main.ts'
},
...
```

The "libs.ts" contains the import of the Leaflet module:

```
import 'leaflet';
```

I'm using Atom as a code editor. It now recognises all the Leaflet classes and methods. I can now do things like this in Angular 2:

```
import {Map, TileLayer} from 'leaflet';
...
this.baseMaps = {
    StreetMap: new TileLayer('mapbox.streets')
};
```

Here is where my problems start. I'm trying to use mapbox.js. What I did was I installed mapbox.js library and typings:

```
npm install mapbox.js --save
typings install mapbox --save
```

This is where I'm stuck. For the life of me I can't figure out how to do what Leaflet managed to do.

```
import 'mapbox';
```

Doesn't work.

```
ERROR in ./src/libs.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'mapbox' in C:\Develop\angular2-webpack-starter\src
 @ ./src/libs.ts 3:0-17
```

I can see "browser.d.ts" has the following:

```
/// <reference path="browser\ambient\leaflet\leaflet.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="browser\ambient\mapbox\mapbox.d.ts" />
```

I thought maybe Mapbox will just work, because it extends the Leaflet library?

It seems that I can basically do something like this, which is the standard javascript way:

```
this.baseMaps = {
    StreetMap: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets')
};
```

But not this:

```
this.baseMaps = {
    StreetMap: new TileLayer('mapbox.streets')
};
```

This obviously doesn't work either:

```
import {Map, TileLayer} from 'mapbox';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the `mapbox.js` NPM module, and it'll include everything you need.

`npm install mapbox.js --save`

See this example. We're using Webpack to do the module loading, and with TypeScript you need to explicitly `import *` for untyped modules.

```
import * as L from 'mapbox.js';

const map = L.mapbox.map('mapContainer', 'mapbox.streets');

// do stuff.
```

Comment: I'm going to mark this solution as accepted, because it works. However, I might just add that it doesn't fully answer the part of my question regarding typings definition (mapbox.d.ts) file and therefore doesn't provide strong types.

Comment: Sir, not working at my end. Please suggest any other.
We are using beta version of Angular i.e 1.5.7

Answer (score 9):

For anyone like me who just wanted to get a map to show in their project, here's how I got it. Based mostly on [Angular2 Mapbox-gl Starter](https://github.com/haoliangyu/angular2-mapboxgl-starter).

**Adding Mapbox-gl to Angular 2 - Webpack and Typescript**

Install the needed packages...
`npm install mapbox-gl --save`
`npm install @types/mapbox-gl --save`
`npm install @types/geojson --save`

Add stuff to webpack...

```
module.exports = function(options) {
  return {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'mapbox-gl': '../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js'
      }
    },
    module: {
      postLoaders: [
        {
          include: /node_modules\/mapbox-gl-shaders/,
          loader: 'transform',
          query: 'brfs'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Add a map.service.ts (For some reason I had to use full relative paths in the imports)...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as mapboxgl from '../../../../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';
import { Map } from '../../../../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';

@Injectable()
export class MapService {
  map: Map<any, any>;

  constructor() {
    (mapboxgl as any).accessToken = 'YOUR_MAPBOX_TOKEN_HERE';
  }
}
```

Add maps to your component...

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MapService } from '../../api/resources/map.service';
import { Map } from '../../../../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  styles: [ require('./my-component.component.less') ],
  template: require('./my-component.component.html'),
  providers: [ MapService ]
})
export class MyComponentComponent {
  constructor(private mapService: MapService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    let map = new Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
      zoom: 5,
      center: [-78.880453, 42.897852]
    });

    this.mapService.map = map;
  }
}
```

Add map div to your html...

```
// my-component.component.html
<div id="map" class="mapboxgl-map"></div>
```

For styles, I use `LESS`, so I imported the mapbox styles there...

```
// my-component.component.less
@import (less) '../../../../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
```

Comment: Getting this error.
 Module '../../../node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js' was resolved to 'path/node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js', but '--allowJs' is not set.