# angular 2 webpack issues with 3rd party library

Tags: angular, webpack, mapbox, angular-cli, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to get a 3rd party library up and running in my `angular-cli` generated project.

I have thus far installed:

```
npm install mapbox-gl --save
npm install @types/mapbox-gl --save
npm install @types/geojson --save
```

In app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import { Map } from 'mapbox-gl';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {
    (mapboxgl as any).accessToken = '****';
  }
  ngOnInit() {

        let map = new Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
            zoom: 5,
           center: [-78.880453, 42.897852]
        });

    }

}
```

`ng build` yields many errors complaining on similar lines:

> ERROR in ./~/mapbox-gl/js/util/util.js Module parse failed:
>   C:_dev\angular-mapbox\node_modules\mapbox-gl\js\util\util. js
>   Unexpected token (15:35) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type. |  * @private |  */ | exports.easeCubicInOut =
>   function(t: number): number { |     if (t <= 0) return 0; |     if (t
>
> > = 1) return 1;  @ ./~/mapbox-gl/js/mapbox-gl.js 26:16-38  @ ./src/app/app.component.ts  @ ./src/app/app.module.ts  @ ./src/main.ts
> >     @ multi main

I was following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931380/mapbox-typescript) (@brandonreid's answer), which has some webpack interim step which I think I need, but not sure how to knit that into given i've used the angular-cli.

On a similar vein I followed [this wrapping project](https://github.com/kuflink/angular2-mapbox) and get exactly the same issue.

Comment: Have you also included the third party component in the app.module.ts as a declaration?

Comment: its not a component its a library

Comment: if its just a library then include it in the starting file, ie. index.html, as an old fashioned util.js file.  Then remove the import from the app.component.ts and use it as is.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: yep that worked thank you. thought id tried it, but obviously not well. would be nice to have it in there correctly...

Comment: That's great to hear! Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the question from the comments above... Since the third party library is not a component, you include it in the starting file, ie. index.html, as an old fashioned util.js file. Then remove the import from the app.component.ts and use it as is.  Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to webpack. Try replacing the

```
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
```

with

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js';
```

Comment: cannot find module 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js'